# How do I escape the "#" and "$" signs unix shell? (In a password argument)

Tags: bash, mongodb, escaping

I'm trying to connect to a mongo database, but the password has special symbols, for example:

```
mongodump ... -p#$123!
```

I've tried wrapping it in quotes, slash escaping, nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it to work with

```
--password='#!123'
```